# PyQt5 Pyqtgraph plot discret

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

At present, for this project, I'm working with matplolib to trace my plot. 
Nevertheless, I wish to convert at pyqtgraph ( Pyqt5). 
I didn't found how trace a discret plot of FFT with pyqtgraph, same the picture. 
Have you an idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an item in which the vertical lines are drawn:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

class LinePlot(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(LinePlot, self).__init__()
        self._data = []
        self.setData(data)

    def setData(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self.generate()

    def generate(self):
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('r', width=2))
        for (t, v) in self._data:
            if v != 0:
                p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, 0), QtCore.QPointF(t, v))

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import random

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    view = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    w.setCentralWidget(view)
    plot = view.addPlot()
    vals = [(i, random.randint(0, 255)) for i in range(30)]
    plot.addItem(LinePlot(vals))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This already says that pyqtgraph shouldn't be used with math. if stem doesn't exist and I have to replace it with my own class creation then matplotlib should always be the case. No one is mentioning that online and I have no clue why.